What is causing this? Error: Incompatible types: got "Boolean" expected "LongInt"
I am writing code for homework, however, the compiler always gives me the following error for the procedure. I honestly have no idea what is wrong about it, I cannot find the mistake. I don't know why it's giving me this error. Does anyone have any idea?

convertNumbers.pas(21,14) Error: Incompatible types: got "Boolean" expected "LongInt"
convertNumbers.pas(42,4) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping

PROGRAM convertNumbers;

TYPE
  aDual = ARRAY[0..15] OF BOOLEAN;

PROCEDURE Dual2Dec (iDecimal: INTEGER; VAR aDualCalc: aDual);
VAR
  iCount: INTEGER;
  bDivision: BOOLEAN;
  iCalculation: INTEGER;

BEGIN
  iCount := 0;    

  WHILE iCount < 16 AND iDecimal > 0 DO  // Error: Incompatible types: got "Boolean" expected "LongInt"
  BEGIN
    iCalculation := iDecimal mod 2;
    IF iCalculation = 0 THEN
      bDivision := FALSE
    ELSE
      bDivision := TRUE;
    aDualCalc[iCount] := bDivision;
    iDecimal := iDecimal div 2;
    iCount := iCount + 1;
  END;
END;

BEGIN

END.


Just for gits and shiggles, try changing that line to WHILE ((iCount < 16) AND (iDecimal > 0)) DO...

Is that program correctly indented?

@DavidTonhofer - Pascal isn't python; indentation is only for humans.

Off topic but I hope it's not the prof who gave the terribad idea of using Hungarian notation. It was a Bad Idea 30 years ago and it hasn't become a better idea since.

@JeffZeitlin Sure, and I happen to be human, so...

@DavidTonhofer - The point that I was trying not to rub your nose in was that you should be matching BEGIN/END pairs, not checking for "correct" indentation.

@JeffZeitlin I know.

@JeffZeitlin that was it, thank you so much, I was getting desperate! lol. I did not know that the brackets were that important"

Slan, since I wasn't certain that that would be the issue, please accept the answer that @Chris posted, since it's the same solution, and he confirmed the reason it worked. (Accepting is clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.)

@Slan If you are unsure, consider the compiler a system under scientific investigation and poke it. Try different things!

@DavidTonhofer I'm new to programming and still learning the syntax of pascal, sort of. I never had anything to do with code before, so it's still kinda hard for me to know what I can do and what I can't. In this case I didn't know you can add brackets! But thank you all so much for helping me out!

In Pascal and has higher precedence than comparison operators, so:
WHILE iCount < 16 AND iDecimal > 0 DO

Parses more like:
WHILE iCount < (16 AND iDecimal) > 0 DO

Than the intended:
WHILE (iCount < 16) AND (iDecimal > 0) DO


Is 16 AND iDecimal an expression of Boolean type? If so, how does it work, what does it mean? If not, why the error message got "Boolean" expected "LongInt"?

Ok, just figured out the answer to my last question: in 16 AND iDecimal, the AND is a bitwise integer operator.
